# Does header file import modules a standard thing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, backwards-compatibility, c++-modules

C++ 20 modules guaranteed backward compatible so modules can import headers.

And Visual Studio introduced [header file import modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170#modules-and-header-files),is this stardard or just a VS thing?

```
// MyProgram.h
import std.core;
#ifdef DEBUG_LOGGING
import std.filesystem;
#endif
```

Comment: Depends on which part of the linked page exactly you talk about. It would probably be better if you included examples of the syntax you talk about, so that it is clear which one you refer to and so that the reference to the external source is not required to understand the question.

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem? If the reply is helpful, you could click '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include` is a preprocessor directive that does a textual copy-and-paste of the text in the target file. Modules didn't change this. Textually copy-and-pasting `import` directives is still textual copy-and-pasting.

So yes, this is standard. Assuming your compiler implements them correctly.

That being said, it's probably not a good idea to have headers `import` things. If you want to build a collection of `import`s used by various files in your system, just build a proper named module and reap the benefits of the module build system. It's OK to `export import` modules.

Answer (score 0):

Newer C standards always maintain backward compatible as much as they can, to prevent porting / migration issues.
However, there might be instances where code changes may be needed, when porting to a newer standard.

Importing modules is a new feature in C++20 standard. Any compiler built using the C++20 standard (modules feature is also available in C++23) allows importing modules.

If your compiler supports C++20 you will need to use the switch:
-fmodules-ts (C++20 'import' is only available when '-fmodules-ts' is specified on the build commands)

In case the compiler by default does not support C++20 you can specify the switch on the build commands:
-std=c++20

Hope that helps answer your question.